# Java, Compare 3 integers, arrange largest, median and smallest

Tags: java, sorting, jvm, int

I have been assigned a homework assignment to prompt the user for 3 positive integers then compare and print them in order of largest, median and smallest.

Prompting and writing a while loop to check if the numbers are positive is fine.  I can also figure out how to print the largest and smallest integer.

(Something like this?)

```
 if (a >= b) 
       if (a >= c) { max= a; if (b >= c) min= c; else min= b; }
       else { max= c; min= b; }
    else if (b >= c)
       { max= b; if (a >= c) min= c; else min= a; }
    else { max= c; if (a >= b) min= b; else min= a; }
```

How would I calculate the middle integer using this same schema?  I would preferably not use an array yet as the professor has not yet explained them.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using `Math.max` and `Math.min`?

Comment: When you set the min=.. you know what the min and what the max is, what about just setting the middle=.. there?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - If he can use library methods, then `Arrays.sort(int[])` gives a 3 line answer.  (Yea I know he would "prefer not to" use arrays ...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store the three numbers in three variables `a b c`, then use your branching logic to determine the order. You have everything you need to solve this problem here.

For example

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
    //Here you determine second biggest, but you know that a is largest
}

if (b > a && b > c) {
    //Here you determine second biggest, but you know that b is largest
}    

if (c > b && c > a) {
    //Here you determine second biggest, but you know that c is largest
}
```

Inside the comments above is where you would determine the `median` and the `smallest` number. The code is wordy, but since you said not to use an array, it's the most straightforward way to understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!  If you vote up my question I will have 15 reputation, then I could vote up your answer as I do not believe it deserves the -1.

Comment: No problem. Not sure why I was downvoted but StackOverflow can be fickle sometimes. Upvoted your question. You can also mark my response as accepted by clicking the checkmark under my score, if you'd like.

Comment: Finally accepted your answer 9 years later @Kon

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a=2;
    int b=4;
    int c=5;

    if(c>b && c>a){
        system.out.println("c is greater");
    }
    if(b>a && b>c){
        system.out.println("b is greater");
    }
    if(a>c && a>b){
        system.out.println("a is greater");
```

Comment: this only explains one part of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Code 1 is to check the biggest number**

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
    // a is biggest number   
}    
if (b > a && b > c) {
    //b is biggest number
}    
if (c > b && c > a) {
    //c is biggest
}
```

**Code 2 is to check the second biggest number**

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
     if(b>c){
         System.out.println(b);
         }
     else{
         System.out.println(c);
         }
}
if (b > a && b > c) {
     if(a>c){
         System.out.println(a);
         }
      else{
          System.out.println(c);
      mm }
}
 if (c > b && c > a) {
      if(b>a){
          System.out.println(b);
          }
       else{
        System.out.println(a);
         }
}
```

**Code 3 is to check the third biggest number or smallest number**

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
     if(b>c){
         System.out.println(c);
         }
     else{
         System.out.println(b);
         }
}
if (b > a && b > c) {
     if(a>c){
         System.out.println(c);
      }
      else{
          System.out.println(a);
       }
}
 if (c > b && c > a) {
      if(b>a){
          System.out.println(a);
          }
       else{
        System.out.println(b);
       }
}
```